# Why my computer doing 3 way handshake with a server 3 times with different ports - Wireshark?

Tags: networking, tcp, ip, wireshark, handshake

I captured packets using Wireshark while my computer is connecting to random web site for my assignment using TCP. Normally, there should be 3 initial packets (SYN, SYN-ACK, ACK) for 3-way handshake before the data transfer starts.

In my case, there are 9 connections, 3 different 3-way handshake; each was done with a different port of my computer. After each of them are accepted, the data transfer continues with only one of the ports.

I couldn't understand the reason behind this. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is common that browsers open multiple connections to a site. Reason for this is that with HTTP/1 a single TCP connection can only handle a single request-response at a time, i.e. multiple requests after each other and not in parallel. To handle multiple requests in parallel a browser needs to have multiple TCP connections open. Since connection setup takes some time browsers might open multiple connections to the server just to have some already established if new requests need to be send.

Comment: @hpsrgb It looks like you're new to Stack Overflow. If this answers your question, please mark it as the answer.