# How does the browser (Google Chrome) send requests to the http server?

Tags: python, sockets, http, request, connection

I created my web server on Python with a persistent connection. I checked the socket for readability and closed the connection when reading an empty string.

I tried to make HTTP requests through the address bar. In the debug output, I noticed that my server after a few seconds after my request accepted another readable connection readable, but I only read an empty line from it. I read that an empty string in most cases means that the connection is closed by the sender. After that I close this connection.

I cannot understand why connections come with empty content.

Please could you help me figure out what is the cause of this and what could it mean (connections with empty line).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why my computer doing 3 way handshake with a server 3 times with different ports - Wireshark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61010657/why-my-computer-doing-3-way-handshake-with-a-server-3-times-with-different-ports) - This explains why the browser is doing multiple connections to the server instead of only the single one you expected.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich, thank you very much, it became clearer